# ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback customize exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, https, ssl-certificate, dotnet-httpclient

I want to do custom certificate validation via ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback property of HttpClientHandler.  However, the callback provided can only return true (for valid certificate) or false (for invalid certifcate).  If the certificate is rejected, on the client i get a standard error message:

"The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback"

which is not very informative.

I would like to give more information in the error message as to why the certificate is invalid, e.g. hostname mismatch, missing certificate, untrusted root, revoked, etc., in order to make it easier for the user to diagnose the problem.  Is it possible to relay this information from the callback somehow?  In particular, can I throw an exception from the callback instead of returning false?  If not, what could be another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing in the callback will probably result in your message making it through correctly, though it will skip the graceful shutdown of the TLS session-in-progress.

A more graceful option might be to wrap the SslStream/HttpClient/etc and have the callback set an instance message when it is about to return false, then intercept the AuthenticationException that's thrown and throw your own instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The graceful option seems better.  It might be diffucult to set the message in the instance though if the same HttpClient is used in multi-threaded environment.  Maybe i should save this info into HttpRequestMessage somehow, since it is passed to the callback?  I guess could use HttpRequestMessage.Options even though this seems like a hack.  I wish there was a way to save this error info on per-request basis.